# Custom error page in cakephp 4 redirect to login page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm using CakeDC/users in my application, and when I created a custom error page and when I test, the application redirects to the login page.

In config/permissions.php

```
    [
        'role' => '*',
        'controller' => 'Error',
        'action' => '*',
        'bypassAuth' => true,
    ],
```

Comment: It should be `'action' => '*'`?

Comment: I forgot to put it in the example, but even though it still redirects to the login page.